# How to write preg_match for a date followed by specific string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to extract date from several HTML documents. The date always follow this pattern:

1. Starting three alphabets of month with first character in uppercase
   i-e Jan.
2. Two digit numerical characters of day of the month i-e 09
3. A comma as a separater
4. Four digit numerical characters of year i-e 2022.

Sample of complete date is Jan 09, 2022

I want to extract only those dates which are wraped in span tags. So, the complete pattern is

```
<span>Jan 09, 2022</span>
```

I am not good at writing preg_match. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>(\w{3} \d{1,2}, \w{4})<\/span>`

`\w` is a meta-character for the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

`{3}` means thrice.

`\d` is a meta-character for the set `[0-9]`.

`{1,2}` means once or twice.

Try it https://regex101.com/r/tNRa73/1

```php
$pattern = '/<span>(\w{3} \d{1,2}, \w{4})<\/span>/'; 

preg_match(
  $pattern,
  $html,
  $matches // <-- The results will be added to this new variable.
);

$matches[1]; // The date will be in the first index because it was
             // the first "capture group" i.e set of parens.


// If you expect multiple dates in one HTML document, then use:
preg_match_all(
  $pattern,
  $html,
  $matches
);

$matches[1]; // Now, the first index is an array of matches of
             // the first "capture group".
```

Comment: `\w`
 matches any word character (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Comment: @rhinosforhire Thankyou so much for your help. Can you please help a bit more by modifying this pattern for the case if value of day is either single digit or double digit. While I used your pattern I found out some dates in documents contains day as a single digit also i-e Jan 9, 2022

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, @vee. @zish, I've changed the quantifier to match once or twice as requested i.e `{1,2}`.